# What's a good (Fedora) Linux app to create ISO image files from CDs and DVDs?

Tags: linux, dvd, fedora, iso-image, compact-disc

I'm thinking of backing up important CDs and DVDs by not simply copy-pasting the files from the CD or DVD, that's why i'd like to create ISO image files instead.  What's a good app for that? It should run smoothly on Fedora 11.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Gnome you can :

1. Insert the CD (or DVD) into the drive. A CD icon should appear on the desktop after it auto mounts
2. Right click on the desktop icon and from the pop up menu select “Copy Disc…”
3. On the small dialogue that appears the “Copy disc to:” field probably displays the CD/DVD writer drive. Change it to “Image File”, if not already selected.
4. Select the Properties button, and the .iso file type.
5. Select the “Copy” button
6. Select “OK”

In KDE I like [K3B](http://k3b.plainblack.com/) - very easy to use.

**Edit**

The above Gnome steps are really only valid for Gnome 2.
As @cept0 pointed out, this doesn't work for Fedora 20, which uses Gnome 3.  A default fedora through Fedora 14 could use the above Gnome steps.  The following will work on Fedora 19 & 20 for sure, Fedora 15 -18, you're on your own ;)

In Gnome 3 you can :

1. Insert the CD (or DVD) into the drive.
2. Run the gnome-disk-utility.  Several ways to do this.  Typing "disc" or "iso" in the activities search area will work.
3. Click on the gear in the upper right corner
4. In the drop down select "Create Disk Image"
5. Change the name & save location if you like and select "Start Creating"

[image: gnome 3 disks screen]

Comment: This one did the trick with the least effort. Thanks, Dave!

Comment: -1 Does not work for Fedora 20 anymore ....

Comment: @cept0: It does! ;-)

Comment: Only works for CDs / DVDs.  dd required for USBs, etc.

Answer (score 11):

`dd` is readily available from the command line:

```
dd if=/dev/cdrom of=/home/sam/myCD.iso bs=2048 conv=sync,notrunc
```

Comment: Very good choice for devices with multiple partitions.

Answer (score 2):

Gnome's nautilus, as [DaveParillo](https://superuser.com/questions/69007/whats-a-good-fedora-linux-app-to-create-iso-image-files-from-cds-and-dvds/69352#69352) suggests, uses Brasero, so if you're not using Gnome, just install Brasero (in Fedora it's a standard package, you might already have it---don't know about other distros), then choose "Copy CD/DVD", and do as Dave says.

Comment: **Brasero sucks**

Answer (score 1):

[AcetoneISO](http://www.acetoneteam.org/) can be the application you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Use Brasero

```
sudo yum install brasero
```

Comment: it works very well for me.

Answer (score -1):

[IsoMaster](http://www.littlesvr.ca/isomaster/) is pretty good and is bundled in every Linux distro.

Comment: IsoMaster is more a bug than a usable software...